Judaism and aesthetics
Is there a religious Jewish perspective, either in terms of Halacha (ie Hiddur Mitzvah) or Hashkafa on aesthetics? If so, are there any aesthetic movements which integrate with Judaism’s criteria for proper aesthetics best? For aesthetics, I’m talking about any manifestation of art, be it writing, sculpture, music, painting etc.

There is a lot of discussion in chassidus about beauty, from tiferet and the source of beauty being harmony (and potentially symmetry). I will see if I can find what I've seen and write something up if you are interested in this angel. I doubt that it's going to be a "halachic" answer though

1: The halachically-best Channukiyahs should be silver. 2: The Torah’s script was changed from Paleo-Hebrew to the Assyrian block script, the latter of which is called “beautiful” in the Talmud, and this is potentially one reason for the script change. 3: It is considered a good thing to beautify Mitzvot (הִדּוּר מצוָּה).

The halachic definition of an Etrog Mehudar does not conform to any classical standard of beauty (IMO), and yet it is described by the Torah as "Hadar" - so I guess the Torah's categorisation does not fully overlap with classic aesthetics?

@Chani Interestingly Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch (Vayikra 23:40) compares favorably the Talmud's criteria for beauty of an etrog with the opinion of a contemporary botanist (does classic aesthetics disagree?)

@ba fascinating!

זֶה אֵלִי וְאַנְוֵהוּ

Rashi on Shemos 26:13 says למדה תורה דרך ארץ, שיהא אדם חס על היפה - The Torah teaches that a person should pay mind to elegance.

@Qwertrl I've seen brass menoros. Do you have the source that says they should be silver?

@Yehudah קיצור שולחן ערוך קל״ט

Note that brass, being a type of non-silver metal, is indeed considered a higher level than something like clay or wood. However, silver specifically is the most מהוּדָר.

On the other hand, שקר החן והבל היופי

@J.W.Tanner That means that such things have no inherent value. However, if beauty is used to further the service of Hashem, it becomes a vessel for goodness, and is thus considered “good”.

The cohanim were required to fit certain physical features and not have defects in their physical appearance and the Cohen gadol's appearance is spoken highly of in the piut mare Cohen said on Yom kipur

There is definitely a role for aesthetics in Judaism.  In the Song at the Sea, the Jews said (Exodus 15:2) זֶ֤ה אֵלִי֙ וְאַנְוֵ֔הוּ, which the Talmud (Shabbos 133b) interprets to mean This Is My God (which by the way is the title of a recommended book by Herman Wouk) and I will beautify Him.  Quoting that passage in the Talmud from Sefaria:

However, here, with regard to circumcision, where we need to fulfill the mitzva of: “This is my God and I will glorify Him,” which requires performing the circumcision in a beautiful manner, indeed, Rabbi Yishmael would agree that the mitzva must be performed as aesthetically as possible.
דְּתַנְיָא: ״זֶה אֵלִי וְאַנְוֵהוּ״, הִתְנָאֵה לְפָנָיו בְּמִצְוֹת: עֲשֵׂה לְפָנָיו סוּכָּה נָאָה, וְלוּלָב נָאֶה, וְשׁוֹפָר נָאֶה, צִיצִית נָאָה, סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה נָאֶה, וְכָתוּב בּוֹ לִשְׁמוֹ בִּדְיוֹ נָאֶה, בְּקוּלְמוֹס נָאֶה, בְּלַבְלָר אוּמָּן, וְכוֹרְכוֹ בְּשִׁירָאִין נָאִין.
What is the source for the requirement of: “This is my God and I will glorify Him”? As it was taught in a baraita with regard to the verse: “This is my God and I will glorify Him [anveihu], the Lord of my father and I will raise Him up.” The Sages interpreted anveihu homiletically as linguistically related to noi, beauty, and interpreted the verse: Beautify yourself before Him in mitzvot. Even if one fulfills the mitzva by performing it simply, it is nonetheless proper to perform the mitzva as beautifully as possible. Make before Him a beautiful sukka, a beautiful lulav, a beautiful shofar, beautiful ritual fringes, beautiful parchment for a Torah scroll, and write in it in His name in beautiful ink, with a beautiful quill by an expert scribe, and wrap the scroll in beautiful silk fabric.


Small addition: The Rashbam (Pesachim 99b) says the reason one shouldn’t eat on Erev Pesach afternoon is כדי שיאכל מצה של מצוה לתיאבון משום הידור מצוה. This seems to imply that the idea of hiddur mitzvah is that it will cause one to do the mitzvah with more excitement. If so, it’s important that the mitzvah be beautiful in the subjective perception of the one doing it, and not based on general beauty standards.
